# Typography - Understanding Practical Font Hinting - Using FontLab VI

Tags: typography

I'm sort of a n00b when it comes to typography - but I have started to learn more using FontLab VI.

I have created a simple custom font - but I still have no idea how to do custom font hinting.  When I use the automated tool, it comes out pretty close, but there are a few issues.

Specifically, the lower angled portions of some characters (e.g. v and w) don't seem to descend as far as other characters.  See below:

[image]
(You might need to zoom in a bit to see what I mean)

How do I fix that?